# Getting Calendar Bookings Error on Power Query

Tags: excel, calendar, powerquery, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to create a table using Power Query that will fetch all the bookings made to an Exchange Email address using Calendar ID.
Is the errors I'm getting because I'm doing something wrong or is it just not possible?

Thanks

```
let
Source = Exchange.Contents("XXXuniversity6@XXXuniversity.onmicrosoft.com"),
Calendar1 = Source{[Name="Calendar"]}[Data],
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Calendar1, each ([DisplayTo] = "Person1" or [DisplayTo] = "Person2"))
in #"Filtered Rows"
```

[Exchange Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1KgB.png)

[PQ Screenshot showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dST35.png)

Answer (score 0):

Similar code works fine for me once I authenticated to exchange server

```
let Source = Exchange.Contents("horseyride@something.com"),
Calendar1 = Source{[Name="Calendar"]}[Data],
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(Calendar1, each ([DisplayTo] = "Person1 Name1; Person2 Name2" or [DisplayTo] = "Person3 Name3; Person4 Name4")),
in #"Filtered Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, mine works fine on the normal email account... but is it possible to do it on an exchange ID (as that has more calendar bookings showing as it's my MS Bookings account)? It seems to let you get in to display the calendar bits, but wont show the body of the calendar item.

Comment: Sorry, I dont have one to test